# Looping causes forced reflow while the same code doesn't cause reflow without loop

Tags: javascript, layout, google-chrome-devtools, web-performance

I found a weird case of forced reflow when we use loop. [Example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reflow-siva-68j58?file=/reflow.js)

In the first case, I have looped through 200 elements and change its class using for loop.

```js
function resize1(){
    let children = parent1.children;
        clicked2 = !clicked2;
    for(let i=0;i<200;i++){
        let child = children[i];
        let { width } = window.getComputedStyle(child);
        isLarge = clicked2 ? i % 2 === 0 : i % 2=== 1;
        if(isLarge){
            child.classList.add('large');
            child.classList.remove('small');
        }
        else{
            child.classList.add('small');
            child.classList.remove('large');
        }
        // size = window.getComputedStyle(child).margin;
    }
}
```

Instead of looping I again went through each child elements and changed the same class.

```js
let width, isLarge, i =0, child;
  
        child = parent.children[i];
        width = window.getComputedStyle(child);
        isLarge = clicked ? i % 2 === 0 : i % 2=== 1;
        if(isLarge){
            child.classList.add('large');
            child.classList.remove('small');
        }
        else{
            child.classList.add('small');
            child.classList.remove('large');
        }
        i++;
    
        child = parent.children[i];
        width = window.getComputedStyle(child);
        isLarge = clicked ? i % 2 === 0 : i % 2=== 1;
        if(isLarge){
            child.classList.add('large');
            child.classList.remove('small');
        }
        else{
            child.classList.add('small');
            child.classList.remove('large');
        }
        i++;
```

(*200 elements)
I know this case is weird but when I checked for performance the second case takes less amount of time in chrome dev tools and reflow also occurs in looping case only.

[image: Performance profiling]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has absolutely nothing to do with looping vs not looping, and everything to do with how you're using `window.getComputedStyle()`.

[This handy gist](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a#calling-getcomputedstyle) outlines which JavaScript properties and methods will force layout/reflow.

> window.getComputedStyle() will force layout in one of 3 conditions:
>
> 1. The element is in a shadow tree
> 2. There are media queries (viewport-related ones). Specifically, one of the following:
> 3. **The property requested is one of the following:**
>
> - **`height`, `width`**

Now, in the looping version of your code, you have this:

```
let { width } = window.getComputedStyle(child);
```

However in the *non*-looping version of your code, you have this:

```
width = window.getComputedStyle(child);
```

What is the difference? `width = window.getComputedStyle(child)` creates a reference to the computed styles object, but it does *not* access the `width` property. You have (perhaps erroneously) created a variable `width` that does *not* request the width property but instead the computed style object itself, which in and of itself is not enough to force a layout.

However, `let { width } = window.getComputedStyle(child)` adds the extra step of destructuring the `width` property to a variable declaration, effectively accessing that property and forcing a layout for *every* iteration of your `for` loop.

You can see the extra forced layout that `let { width } = window.getComputedStyle(child)` causes in the performance timeline (Safari):

[image]

If you modify the non-looping version of your code to access the `width` property of `getComputedStyle()` for all 200 cases, you get the same forced layout in the non-looping portion:

[image]

Or, you could simply remove all uses of `window.getComputedStyle()`, since in the current version of your code it is not used for anything, and eliminate the forced layout entirely.

[image]